# Can't expose data as graph in nagios

Tags: jms, jmx, nagios

I am monitoring Message Count attribute of JMS Queue using Nagios. For that I am using check_jmx plugin and it gives the output as "JMX OK MessageCount=400". I configured graph for this service, but when click  on graph icon it shows no data available. This service not generating any rrd file. How can I configure graph for my message count monitoring service? In graph i want to show message count/hour. Whether I have to use another plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nagios graphing addons such as PNP4Nagios use the performance data of the plugin output which is everything after the `|`.  Run the plugin on the command line and see if it's outputting performance data, and try different verbosity options by adding `-vvv` to `check_jmx`.

[More info on performance data](http://nagiosplug.sourceforge.net/developer-guidelines.html#AEN201)

[check_jmx usage](http://code.google.com/p/jmxquery/wiki/Usage)

Answer (score 0):

As i can't tell from your text, which plugin you are using in order to gernerate the graphs, i myself recommend PNP4Nagios.
Once installed it is working really great.

for your problem:

> and it gives the output as "JMX OK MessageCount=400".

if this is the messages / hour, you dont even have to change anything.

if it's not, you might include the code of the plugin in its current version on your nagios to your question or modyfie yourself ( store / grab messagecount and timestamp in order to calculate your messages / hour )